# Python- What would be the best way to hold a list in memory in order to minimize I/O?

Tags: python, file-io

I'm processing PDF's and saving the output (some info about each line in file) as a csv. However, I don't want to save each time I process a page (pdfminer does one page at a time).

What would be the best way to hold the list in memory, add to the list each time a page is processed and only save once the whole pdf document is processed?

I'm trying to avoid a global list variable but would this be a justified use case? Also I tried using both streamio and bytesio but they don't take lists.

FYI:
I'm using pdfminer which allows you to iterate over each line in the pdf document and for each line I'm saving some meta data as a list. Then that list goes to a 'page list' which is a list of lists.

example output:

page_list = [[line_no_1, average_char_size_1, average_length_1], [line_no_2, average_char_size_2, average_length_2]...ect]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep the whole list for other purposes, you could skip it completely. Instead of saving the information for later, dump it immediately:

```
with open(....) as f:
    for page_results in ...:
        f.write(format_results_as_csv(page_results))
        f.write("\n")
```

This way you don't have to hold on to the previous page results, you write each page information only once, and under the covers you're using standard file buffering (so multiple short writes will be buffered and written to the file in one batch).

If you do want to keep all of the results while you process the document and avoid global variables, you'll have to figure a way to pass the list up into function processing each page.